# Some infinite series (just for fun!)

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recreational-mathematics, telescopic-series

I have a few infinite series problems that I think MSE might enjoy, whose answers I already know:

> $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{n-2^n}}{1+2^{-2^n}}=\text{?}$$
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{4^{n+2^n}}{(1+4^{2^n})^2}=\text{?}$$
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3^n(1+2\cdot3^{-3^n})}{2\cosh(3^n\ln 3)+1}=\text{?}$$

After these all get answered, I will post explanations of how *I* came up with answers for them. Have fun!

Comment: Why should we care about these particular series, and why do you think your post here should remain open?

Comment: Although I presume some people might enjoy this challenge, remember this is Q&A site, and not a site to post weekly/monthly/daily challenges.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Better this than another question asking to do someone's hw...

Answer (score 2):

The tag *telescoping* is a great hint:

\begin{align*}
A_n &:= \frac{2^n}{2^{2^n}-1}
&\Rightarrow & \qquad A_n - A_{n+1} = \frac{2^n}{2^{2^n}+1} \\
B_n &:= \frac{4^n \cdot 4^{2^n}}{(4^{2^n}-1)^2} 
&\Rightarrow & \qquad B_n - B_{n+1} = \frac{4^n \cdot 4^{2^n}}{(4^{2^n}+1)^2} \\
C_n &:= \frac{3^n}{3^{3^n}-1} 
&\Rightarrow & \qquad C_n - C_{n+1} = \frac{3^n(3^{3^n}+2)}{3^{2\cdot 3^n}+3^{3^n} + 1}
\end{align*}

From these, we obtain

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{2^{2^n}+1}
&= \lim_{N\to\infty} (A_0 - A_{N+1}) = 1 \\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{4^n \cdot 4^{2^n}}{(4^{2^n}+1)^2}
&= \lim_{N\to\infty} (B_0 - B_{N+1}) = \frac{4}{9} \\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{3^n(3^{3^n}+2)}{3^{2\cdot 3^n}+3^{3^n} + 1}
&= \lim_{N\to\infty} (C_0 - C_{N+1}) = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

---

For a generalization, let $a \geq 2$ be an integer and consider

$$ P_n = \frac{a^n}{X^{a^n}-1}. $$

Then it is not hard to check that

$$
P_n - P_{n+1}
= \frac{a^n \sum_{k=0}^{a-2} (a-1-k) X^{k \cdot a^n}}{\sum_{k=0}^{a-1} X^{k \cdot a^n}}
$$

So if $|X| > 1$, we obtain

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^n \sum_{k=0}^{a-2} (a-1-k) X^{k \cdot a^n}}{\sum_{k=0}^{a-1} X^{k \cdot a^n}} = P_0 = \frac{1}{X-1}. \tag{*}$$

Then

- The 1st series corresponds to $a = 2$ and $X = 2$ applied to $\text{(*)}$.
- The 2nd series corresponds to $a = 2$ and $X = 4$ applied to the derivative of $\text{(*)}$ w.r.t. $X$.
- The 3rd series corresponds to $a = 3$ and $X = 3$ applied to $\text{(*)}$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1-2}+S_1&=\lim_{N\to\infty}(\frac{1}{1-2}+\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{2^{n}}{1+2^{2^n}})\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}(\frac{1}{1-2}+\frac{1}{1+2}+\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{2^{n}}{1+2^{2^n}})\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}(\frac{2}{1-2^2}+\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{2^{n}}{1+2^{2^n}})\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{2^{N+1}}{1-2^{2^{N+1}}}\\
&=0
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(4^{-2^{-1}}-4^{2^{-1}})^2}-S_2&=\frac{1}{(4^{-2^{-1}}-4^{2^{-1}})^2}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{4^{n+2^n}}{(1+4^{2^n})^2}\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}(\frac{1}{(4^{-2^{-1}}-4^{2^{-1}})^2}-\frac{1}{(4^{-2^{-1}}+4^{2^{-1}})^2}-\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{4^{n}}{(4^{-2^{n-1}}+4^{2^{n-1}})^2})\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}(\frac{4}{(4^{-2^{0}}-4^{2^{0}})^2}-\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{4^{n}}{(4^{-2^{n-1}}+4^{2^{n-1}})^2})\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{4^{N+1}}{(4^{-2^{N}}-4^{2^{N}})^2}\\
&=0
\end{align}

Same thing for $S_3$. Note that $\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$. Just some calculations.